# Screen to print font faces

Tags: html, css, fonts, print-style

What is your normal method on styling print style sheets when it comes to font faces.

Traditionally serif fonts are better for printed media, but if the sans serif font is still clear and legible, would it be a better option for a print style sheet, if it made the print outs match the website more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the same font as on the website. The only things I change are the font-color and background-color for light text on dark background. Using the same fonts the print out look more like your actual page and the line breaks will usually stay at the same position.

If you have a website like a blog or any page that has it's main focus on text, there is not argument against using serif fonts for the print out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want the print out too look like.

If youre trying to make it look exactly like the screen version, then obviously you don't want to change anything.

If youre trying to make the printout as legible as possible without retaining the same look and feel as the screen, then it is a good idea to replace the fonts, adjust the colours, line and letter spacing, sizes etc.